# Computing $4^{m+1} \cdot 9^{n-1}$ in terms of $2^m \cdot 3^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

So I got this math question that I have to do. Unfortunately I don't understand a thing. The question is:

> If $2^m \cdot 3^n = a$, what is $4^{m+1} \cdot 9^{n-1}$?

I will be grateful for any and all help.

Comment: $4^{m+1}9^{n-1}=\frac{\left(2^m\cdot 3^n\right)^2\cdot 4}{9}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice, $$4^{m+1}\cdot 9^{n-1}$$
$$=(2^2)^{m+1}\cdot (3^2)^{n-1}$$
$$=(2)^{2m+2}\cdot (3)^{2n-2}$$
$$=2^{2m}\cdot 2^2\cdot 3^{2n}\cdot 3^{-2}$$
$$=\frac{4}{9}(2^{2m}\cdot 3^{2n})$$
$$=\frac{4}{9}(2^{m}\cdot 3^{n})^2$$
Setting $2^{m}\cdot 3^{n}=a$ 
$$=\frac{4}{9}(a)^2=\color{red}{\frac{4}{9}a^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$4^{m+1}\cdot 9^{n-1}= 2^{2(m+1)} \cdot 3^{2(n-1)} = 2^{2m}\cdot 2^2 \cdot 3^{2n} \cdot 3^{-2}  \\ = \frac{4}{9}(2^m \cdot 3^n)^2 =  ... $$

I trust you can finish it off.